# I have a nested Generic List. I want to bind it with datagridview in vb.net. when i bind the list, the nested column only fill with its heading

Tags: .net, vb.net, list, generics, datagridview

I have a class of Item

```
 Public Class Item
        Public Property ItemID() As Integer
        Public Property ItemName() As String
        Public Property itemCategory() As ItemCategory
 End class      

---------
Another Class of ItemCategory

Public Class ItemCategory
    Public Property ItemCategoryID() As Integer
    Public Property ItemCategoryName() As String
End Class
----------
```

when i get data in a List(of item) class from Database
it returns these columns.

1. itemID
2. itemName
3. itemCategory

   3(a) itemCategoryID
   3(b) itemCategoryName

when i bind this list with Datagridview, this shows only three columns and third column fill with column name 'ItemCategory'. I need to show itemCategoryID and itemCategoryName in datagridview.

Comment: That's not going to happen by magic.  A grid will only create a column for an actual property or a property descriptor.  As you don't have those properties, you would need property descriptors, which means a custom type descriptor. That's a topic that you would need to research and attempt to implement for yourself.  If you encounter an actual issue doing so, we can try to help with that specifically. As it though, the subject is too broad for a specific answer.

Comment: By the way, I just tested whether it was possible to create the columns yourself and set the `DataPropertyName` to a value like "ItemCategory.ItemCategoryID" and it didn't work.  The cells were empty in those columns and entering values had no effect on the bound items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @jmcilhinney pointed outed there no magic and `datagridview` needs to know how `ItemCategory` should be displayed.

One option is create "viewmodel" class which will provide properties for `DataGridView`.

Classes populated from database:
(You don't need duplicate class name in every property and properties will reads much easily without class name prefixes)

```
Public Class Item
    Public Property ID As Integer
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Category As ItemCategory
End class      

Public Class ItemCategory
    Public Property ID As Integer
    Public Property Name As String
End Class
```

Then create viewmodel class, which will represent all properties required for DatagridView

```
Public Class ItemViewModel
    Private ReadOnly _item As Item

    Public Property Id As String
        Get
            Return _item.ID
        End Get
    End Property

    ' Add setter if you want edit values through DataGridView
    Public Property Name As String
        Get
            Return _item.Name
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Property CategoryId As String
        Get
            Return _item.Category.ID
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Property CategoryName As String
        Get
            Return _item.Category.Name
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Sub New(item As Item)
        _item = item
    End Sub
End class
```

Then you can bind viewmodel to the DataGridView

```
Dim items As List(Of Item) = LoadFromDatabase()

Dim viewmodels = items.Select(Function(item) new ItemViewModel(item)).ToList()

myDataGridView.DataSource = viewmodels
```